# function when user not logged in cant see page wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to add a function to Wordpress to prevent users from seeing the page if they are not logged in. I am following a youtube video and it works fine in the video but It doesn't work for me. I think it is has something to do with the `is_page` function.

This is my code:

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'members_only');
function members_only(){
    if( is_page('super-secret') && ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url() );
        die();
    }

}
```

The page I'm on when I try to use this code is 'testproject.test/2020/09/22/super-secret'

Comment: Share the YouTube video link with exact timing it may help to get an accurate answer

Comment: That URL doesn't look like a standard page url - do you have custom permalinks, or is this a post or media attachment or something else? Note that "page" in WP has a very specific meaning, it doesn't mean any web page on the site.

Answer (score 1):

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'members_only');
function members_only(){
    if( is_page('super-secret') && ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $url = https://www.example.com
        wp_redirect( $url);
        exit;
    }
}
```

Use this sample of code in functions.php but please reconfirm that (super-secret) is a correct slug of page?

Comment: http://testproject.test/2020/09/22/super-secret/ this is the page im on when i try to use the code i provided

Comment: find id of this page(testproject.test/2020/09/22/super-secret). it will be easy for you to target this page. Then use it (if(is_page("id of page or post") && !is_user_logged_in()))

Comment: @DamianBloemhof Please edit your question with any additional information, as other users might not see it in comments. (I've added it to your question this time)

Answer (score 1):

Replace `wp_redirect( home_url() );` by `wp_redirect( bloginfo('url') );`.